# UIActivityIndicatorView is not animating, why?

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an UIActivityIndicatorView which I start and stop on an notification which I receive from the Notification Center. Although I receive the notifications and I call the start and stop via 'performSelectorOnMainThread' it does not start animating, and does not become visible.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)stopAnimation:(id)sender {
    if( _saveActivityIndicatorView.isAnimating ) {
        [_saveActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    }
}

-(void)startAnimation:(id)sender {
    if( !_saveActivityIndicatorView.isAnimating ) {
        [_saveActivityIndicatorView startAnimating];
    }
}

-(void)saveStarted{
    NSLog(MRVaccinationEventsUpdateStarted);
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startAnimation:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
}

-(void)saveCompleted{
    NSLog(MRVaccinationEventsUpdateCompleted);
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimation:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

And this is how I post and observe the notifications (both in the same file):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(saveStarted)
                                             name:MRVaccinationEventsUpdateStarted
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(saveCompleted)
                                             name:MRVaccinationEventsUpdateCompleted
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MRVaccinationEventsUpdateStarted object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MRVaccinationEventsUpdateCompleted object:nil];
```

Note, that I DO RECEIVE the notifications.
What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Most likely explanation: `_saveActivityIndicatorView` is nil

Comment: Not this will solve the problem but on the two calls to `performSelector...`: 1) Why do you pass `self` to `withObject:` and 2) Why do you pass `YES` to `waitUntilDone:`?

Comment: @jrturton No, it is definitively not nil, but an IBOutlet in the storyboard

Comment: @maddy setting both to `nil` and `NO` will not work either...

Comment: @mradlmaier Just because `_saveActivityIndicatorView` is from an outlet doesn't mean it can't be `nil`. Did you actually check at runtime to see for sure?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the start and stop animation's are in the same loop.

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MRVaccinationEventsUpdateStarted object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MRVaccinationEventsUpdateCompleted object:nil];

You should post the second notification after some time, like

/// three seconds

```
delayInSeconds = 3;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MRVaccinationEventsUpdateCompleted object:nil];
});
```